# How to concurrently process spring integration jms channels

Tags: spring, concurrency

I've got a JMS connectionFactory that a number of spring integration jms inbound-gateways use. They work fine, but only one message at a time. I'd like to make them handle N concurrent messages at a time in different threads.

The code I've got now is as follows.

spring-config.xml

```
<import resource="commons/jmsConnectionFactory.xml"/>
<import resource="chain/chain1.xml"/>
<import resource="chain/chain2.xml"/>
```

jmsConnectionFactory.xml

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL">
        <value>failover:(tcp://mqmaster:61616,tcp://mqslave:61616)?jms.prefetchPolicy.all=1&amp;randomize=false</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

chains all look something like this

```
<int:channel id="fooChannel"/>
<int-jms:inbound-gateway request-channel="fooChannel" request-destination-name="foo" extract-request-payload="true" />
<int:chain input-channel="fooChannel">
  <int-http:outbound-gateway
     url="...."
     http-method="GET" 
     extract-request-payload="true" />
  <int:object-to-string-transformer />
</int:chain>
```

I know that I can add "concurrent-consumers" and "max-concurrent-consumers" to the inbound-gateway to make the gateway process multiple messages. That would result though in having each chain/gateway handling it's threads managed independently. I would like some way to define a common thread pool for everyone using the JMS connection. This would allow me to specify 5 threads and have them allocated among the gateways based on what messages the server is supplying, but constraining the consuming server to a manageable amount of work.

What modifications are needed to do the processing with multiple threads? And how do I limit the number of threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Inbound Gateway** is an extension of **Message-Driven Channel Adapter** so you can use all properties `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` provides. One of them defines number of concurrent consumers container uses:

```
<int-jms:inbound-gateway
    request-channel="fooChannel"
    request-destination-name="foo"
    extract-request-payload="true"
    concurrent-consumers="10" />
```

You can find more information [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RC2/reference/html/jms.html#jms-message-driven-channel-adapter).

Update: It appears you can specify reference to your container implementation in `inbound-gateway` using `container` attribute. That said you can reuse one instance of task executor between your containers and gateways:

```
<int-jms:inbound-gateway
    request-channel="fooChannel"
    request-destination-name="foo"
    extract-request-payload="true"
    container="fooChannelContainer" />

<bean id="fooChannelContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer" destroy-method="destroy">
    ...
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="jmsTaskExecutor" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been a bit clearer. I'll modify my question to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: I am sure you can assign `taskExecutor` to `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`, this is a way to share one thread pool between all containers. But I am not sure if you can do it via *int-jms* namespace.

Answer (score 1):

As hoaz suggested, a taskExecutor is the solution.

```
<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="4"/>
```

and

```
<int:channel id="fooChannel">
  <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
</int:channel>
```