# How to configure 1 thread limit for the clientOutboundChannel of spring Message Broker?

Tags: java, spring-websocket

This is a question related to:

[SockJS receive stomp messages from spring websocket out of order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689838/sockjs-receive-stomp-messages-from-spring-websocket-out-of-order)

But I cannot understand how to limit 1 thread in the message broker.

Comment: You can find it how to do it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40496644/7123191)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe define a task-executor with a pool size of 1, and set it as dispatcher for your outbound channel? Can't test it right now but it might work.

Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16724743/6404321 and here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-configuration-performance

Answer (score 0):

You can config another attribute with registration instance.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.taskExecutor().maxPoolSize(1);
    }

}
```